# how to setOnItemClickListner in list to play audio

Tags: java, android

I am new to android please help me to play audio on list item click in fragment. I am using this code but on item click my app gets crash showing error.

I have tried the below code but my app crashes on click on item:

```java
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

        static MediaPlayer mediaPlaye;
        int audioIndex;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

            ListView audioView = view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
            final ArrayList<String> audioList = new ArrayList<>();

            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
            final Cursor audioCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

            if (audioCursor != null) {
                if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

                        audioList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioIndex));
                    } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            audioCursor.close();

            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),R.layout.tectcolor, audioList);

            audioView.setAdapter(adapter);

            audioView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Uri u = Uri.parse(audioList.get(i).toString());
                    mediaPlaye = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), u);
                    mediaPlaye.start();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }
```

I am expecting to play audio on item click in fragment.

Comment: Hi Baasit, Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please provide the crash stack trace so that we will have more idea on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

u must setOnclick in your Custom Adapter.

when u set onClick on your List, Android check all of your view of List and it will cause a crash.

create an adapter and override onClick in there.

have good coding...